# How to keep track of which buttons have been pressed jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want create simple calculator using only jquery. When I try to track which button is pressed from the list (`name=numbers`), it displays the value of the first button. For example, I constantly get 1

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Z:\ПИ-313\2 подгруппа\Баталова Шаниязов\Веб  - технологии\Веб - технологии\jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="field" type="text"/>
        <input type="button" value="<<">
        <input type="button" value="C">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button name="numbers" value="1">1</button>
        <button name="numbers" value="2">2</button>
        <button name="numbers" value="3">3</button>
        <input type="button" value="+">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="numbers" value="4">
        <input type="button" name="numbers" value="5">
        <input type="button" name="numbers" value="6">
        <input type="button" value="-">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="numbers" value="7">
        <input type="button" name="numbers" value="8">
        <input type="button" name="numbers" value="9">
        <input type="button" value="*">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="numbers" value="0">
        <input type="button" value=",">
        <input type="button" value="/">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="calc">=</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(':button[name=numbers]').click(function() {
                var number = $(':button[name=numbers]').val();
                $('#field').val(number);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is because they have the same `name`. `name` must be unique. For your need, you should use `class` attribute.

Comment: Try this `var number = $(this).val();` [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/97L00tLg/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It is because with `':button[name=numbers]'` you select all buttons with the name `numbers`, which, in your code snippet, means all of them. You get the first value: 1.

In Javascript you have *`this`*. In your `click()` function `this` is 'the item clicked'. In this case perfect, beause you want the value of 'the item clicked':

```
var totalSum = Number( $('#field').val() ); // easier to save if outside the click;
$(':button[name="numbers"]').click(function() {
    $('#field').val( totalSum + this.value);
});
```

---

Little code review, this is what I've done:

- Moved the totalSum out of the click. You can now do other computations with it, without having to select it from the DOM
- I used `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`. jQuery internally does the same, we just do it directly. Using native javascript where possible will very often be faster and more lightweight.
- I just added the value directly in the `.val()` function. This will save you a line of code (while maintaining readability) and you don't save it in the memory now. It's a small value, but do this trick 1000 times and you will feel the difference. If you must save it in a variable, use `let`  instead of `var` (and google why :) )
- You use `name=` and them give them all the same name. They must be unique. I think you're looking for `class=`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this)` to get the clicked button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(':button[name=numbers]').click(function() {
          var number = $(this).val();
          $('#field').val(number);
      }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it. Replace this:

```
var number = $(':button[name=numbers]').val();
$('#field').val(number);
```

by this:

```
var number = $(this).val();
$('#field').val($('#field').val() + number);
```

The mistake is that in your event you are always getting the first element instead of the clicked one. 
Second is you are just setting the value of the retrieved data instead of concatenating with whats already existing.

[Here is the **JSfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/f4mdkhzk/)